# Right Hand Rule?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

I'm trying to determine what the correct right hand rule is, but Google isn't helping. I've seen three different versions of Fleming's Right Hand Rule now, and I'm very confused.

Here are three different versions I've been seeing:

[image: There's this:]

[image: There's this:]

[image]

Would someone be able to explain which is correct and why the wrong ones exist?

Comment: I don't see how they are equivalent. If you orient your hand in a way such that all three axes line up for all three versions, the axes labels are not the same.

Comment: The last one says motion, and not force. That's not the same thing.

Comment: What is the difference? Whens should motion be used and when should force be used?

Comment: Yeah. There are several versions, and they can tend to cause confusion.

Comment: I tend to select one and stick with it. How about the second one? When motion is discussed, they're often taking about generators, specifically, as far as I can recall. A left hand rule is also provided, but it's superfluous. You should be able to use the second one for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the relationship $\vec F=\vec I \times \vec B$ to hold in all cases (direction wise at least. If you were looking at calculating actual numbers you would need to multiply the cross product by a length). You will see that in the first two this is obviously true. In the last one the wording is confusing. It is correct if you take "motion" to be the initial velocity of a positive charge and "current" to be the force, but I'm not sure this word substitution is justified.

Therefore I would not look at the final picture. The first two are valid though.

---

I prefer the first one based on a fun memory device. Your fingers are like grass in a "field", when you push on something with a force you use your palm, and the velocity or current is the other one (props to someone who can make a good analogy for the thumb being the velocity or current. The best I can think of is hitch hiking?).

Comment: Oh I see. I had been using the version in the first picture for a long time, and it worked until I was doing AC generators when all of a sudden the direction is wrong. The "I" in the right hand rule should be the rotation of the generator, and the "F" is actually the induced current in the generator. I had mistakenly been under the impression that the current induced is "I" (I think you'll understand why I made that mistake) and the rotation of the armature is "F". Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Spica It you find this answer helpful then you can show this by upvoting. If it sufficiently answers it more than the other answers you can also select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

All the diagrams are correct if they are used in the correct context.

There are many right-hand rules and the fact that you mention the name Fleming probably contributes to your confusion as is illustrated below.

[image]

You will note that there are two Fleming's rules.

One for the left hand is for motors and one for the right hand is for generators.
As an aide-memoire the following nomenclature is often used:

$\Large \rm F$irst finger $\rightarrow$ magnetic $\Large \rm F$ield direction
se$\Large \rm C$ond finger $\rightarrow$ $\Large \rm C$urrent direction
thu$\Large \rm M$b $\rightarrow$ $\Large \rm M$otion implying force for a motor

So your third diagram is the same as my right hand diagram and refers to the rule for generators.

Your first two diagrams are variations of using the right hand to find the direction of the force for equations like $\mathbf F = \mathbf I \times \mathbf B$ and $\mathbf F =  q\mathbf v \times \mathbf B$ as illustrated below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All three versions are correct. The law that we are looking at here is $f=q v \times B$. Suppose that we have a magnetic field pointing horizontally due north and a proton traveling horizontally due east, then the force is perpendicular to both, so it must be either vertically up or vertically down. So let’s apply all three rules, fixing the field and the velocity and seeing if the rule says that the force will be up or down.

In the first one the fingers are north, the thumb is east, so the palm is up.

In the second the middle finger is north, the index finger is east, so the thumb is up.

In the third one the index finger is north, the thumb is east, so the middle finger is up. (I think that is what this one is saying, but the wording is odd, it may be referring to a completely different law)

All three identify the force as being vertically up, so they all agree and are all correct.

Comment: The last one doesn't identify any force

Comment: Yeah, I think it may be showing a different law than $ f=q v \times B$. I think @Spica needs to check the source for that third one and identify the law being described

Comment: Yeah I can't figure it out. I disregard it in my answer. But if you can figure it out then go for it :)

Comment: I just put in a parenthetical comment making a bit of a disclaimer. I think the picture doesn’t belong, but you could certainly make a right hand rule as I describe, so I will leave the description in.

Comment: I believe the third one might be an application for AC generator setup? If you take "motion" to be the motion of the armature's rotation, and "current" to be the induced current then it works

Comment: Yes, that could be. Then the current is more properly labeled as an electromotive force, which would make it more consistent with the others.

Answer (score 0):

Using your right-hand: point your index finger in the direction of the charge's velocity, v, (recall conventional current). Point your middle finger in the direction of the magnetic field, B. Your thumb now points in the direction of the magnetic force, F(magnetic).

Answer (score 0):

The first image says that $(\vec{v}, \vec{B}, \vec{F})$ is a right-oriented orthogonal frame.

The second image says that $(\vec{F}, \vec{v}, \vec{B})$ is a right-oriented orthogonal frame. But $(\vec{F}, \vec{v}, \vec{B})$ is just a cyclic permutation of $(\vec{v}, \vec{B}, \vec{F})$ and orientation is preserved under cyclic permutation. Therefore this is equivalent to the first image.

The third image says that $(\vec{v}, \vec{B}, \vec{I})$ is a right-oriented orthogonal frame. But $\vec{I}$ has the same direction as $\vec{F}$ so this one is also equivalent to the first image.

Answer (score -3):

Experimentally, when you have a straight conductor moving in a magnetic field as per above diagram for Fleming's Right Hand Rule, you experience zero current which means that the rule is flawed.
I have set up the experiment and proved it to be so.

Comment: Just to clarify, the thumb in both the rules are actually Motion and not Force. The RHR is for induced current and the LHR is for induced motion.

Comment: Go back to Faradays laws of electromagnetic induction and you will realise that the laws only apply to coils. There is no induced current in a straight conductor!. Also, when you approach an enamelled conductive coil with a magnet, current is produced. In such a case which is the way generators are manufactured, the motion and the field is in the same direction. Once again, since Flemings Right Hand Rule is reported to be used for generators, it fails miserably to explain this